# Subsume - usage

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

Can you use 'subsume' as an verb of replacement? For example: Medea *subsumes* her pain into others' suffering.

Answer (score 3):

[Subsume](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/subsume) has the following meaning and usage:

> - usually passive] subsume something + adv./prep. (formal) to include something in a particular group and not consider it separately.
>
>   - All these different ideas can be subsumed under just two broad categories.
>       The new party subsumed several small left-wing parties.

You are probably thinking about ***"[substitute](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/substitute)".***

Comment: Yes, a big difference between the two words.